# How to programmatically reset a users password in Professional Edition Org

Tags: apex, api, soap-api, soap, professional-edition

**Use Case:** I would like to know how to programmatically send a reset password email to a user in professional edition.

Currently for any edition outside of Professional Edition, this can be done via the SOAP API and using the rest password call. However, Salesforce says that the SOAP API is not available for PE Orgs. Therefore, has anyone solutioned a way to reset a PE Org's password programmatically?

Below are the documents we are using for our Enterprise Edition Orgs:

1. [Here is the link to the Reset Password Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_resetpassword.htm)
2. [Here is the link stating which Editions can use the Soap API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm)

Comment: You can purchase an API addon package for PE, check with the Salesforce account executive

Comment: @DavidCheng do I have to be part of the ISV / Partner Program in order to have my client utilized the API Add on? IE make the call from my app to their Salesforce org without having gone through Salesforce review?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm

Comment: The isv program is only if you are going to build apps to be installed from the app exchange. If you are writing an external app to access Salesforce API, you don't need to worry about that